# Raspberry Pi 4 does not boot from USB. Only from SD Card

Tags: bootloader

My Pi does not want to boot from a USB SSD that I connected through an ADATA rack. The rack does not have a power supply of its own, but to power the Pi I use an Macbook Pro Apple charger on which it is written that it can deliver 3.0A at 20.3V, therefore I believe that is not the problem.
I followed the instructions from this [guide](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/boot-raspberry-pi-4-usb)
in order to boot from USB, but to no avail
Whenever I plug only the SSD, at first the green LED appears to be blinking normally, in no clear pattern, but after a few seconds it starts to blink consistantly, every second, however I can't really tell the number of times.
I installed on the SD card a 64-bit version of Raspbian using the rpi-imager tool

Edit: I don't have a mini HDMI cable, therefore I am not able to see what is on the screen

Comment: Tom'sHardware is a generally reliable source of information. I'd recommend that you first review the comments following the article. If you don't find an answer there, repeat the process to find whatever it is that has been overlooked, and failing that - post a question to "Tom". The authors of the procedure are in the best position to help you.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't boot? You mentioned the LED, but haven't mentioned anything about what you can see on your TV/Monitor

Comment: I forgot to mention my Pi is headless, since I, unfortunately, don't have a mini HDMI cable

Comment: @Whitewolf3131 20.3v? Any RPi input voltage over 6v WILL damage the board. Stay between 4.7v and 5.25v to be on the safe side. Luckily, most USB chargers will not provide other voltages than ~5v to unknown devices. If it cant supply 3A at 5v then it's no good. Minimum=2.5A PLUS your SSDs power requirements at ~5v.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot through the Internet, I found out that the problem was the ADATA enclosure that I had. In order to fix it i had to add to my `cmdline.txt` from the `/boot` partition another setting:
`usb-storage.quirks=<usb_id>:u` where <usb_id> is the id of the enclosure which you can get by running the `lsusb` command.
[Here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=245323) is a link to the forum I found that helped me.